# Sound card driver multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx series

Tags: drivers, sound

Please, advise me how to solve the problem with sound. There is no sound devices had been detected by Ubuntu (in Windows I had)  I have Ubuntu 17.10 and the devices listed below.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 36) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 298
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 91000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4M]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 343
    Memory at 9183b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 297
    Memory at 91800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 344
    Memory at 91700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 91600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c 
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
```